Deployment - same github repo client/server
I'm currently working on my exam project, and one of the requirements is to deploy it. However, our school hasn't really taught us how to deploy projects
I have a GitHub repository that contains both a frontend folder (React) and a backend folder (Node/Express), and I'm also using a MariaDB database for my project.
Deploying the frontend was simple with Vercel since I could specify the frontend folder. For the backend, I tried using Railway, but I couldn't choose which folder to deploy, so it didn't work.
Is there another way to deploy my backend from the same repository? Or would it be better to separate the backend into its own repository for deployment purposes? Do anyone have other suggestions for deployment? It's just a small project, so I'm not too keen on spending money on it, but I can if it makes the process easier.

Seems you are deploying a simple form of a monorepo. We have a guide here that shows how to deploy this on Railway https://docs.railway.com/guides/monorepo#deploying-an-isolated-monorepo
